# how to add background color for menu items?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 fl logo">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/main-logo.png" alt="logo" /> 
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="mobile">
                    <a id="mobile-menu" href="#">
                        <div class="mob-bar"><span></span></div>
                    </a>
             </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 right-nav" id="right-nav">

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php">HOME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="aboutus.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href="service.php">SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="news.php">NEWS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactus.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 fl right-3">
                <div class="fl search-icon">
                    <a href="http://www.1008jobs.com/search/normal" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="slideouticons">
                    <input id="togglebox" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="togglebox" class="mainlabel"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i></label>
                    <div class="iconswrapper">
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" title="Facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" title="Google Plus"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" title="Pinterest"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

These is my code. this code i have included in php file and calling this file to all pages. so how can i give background color for nav-items using jquery or javascript. if i am using .addclass to that a tag the page will reloading and script again starting as a existing level. so please some different ways to add that one.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please add your code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: Very unclear what you are trying to ask, resp.what your _actual_ problem is. _“if i am using .addclass to that a tag the page will reloading and script again starting as a existing level.”_  - what do you even mean by that? Please describe your problem properly; go read [ask] if you are unsure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
.right-nav ul li{
  background: #333;
}
```